# Is there anyone who cares about the site being friendly for beginners?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

One of the stack sites I'm a member of has always made me feel that it is too harsh on beginners. Those with several Ks of reputation act too strictly on beginners in comments. For example, in some questions which are not asked in proper technical language, but it is very apparent that what one beginner is trying to ask, they'll show-off some "heavy"  words and/or try to troll the questioner and are more likely to demoralise than help an individual. It adversely affects both, questioner and impression of the stack community on a visitor.

Like come on,  we all once started from beginning, why can't we be kind? Until when are we going to allow bullying in comments? Haven't you felt that trolling anytime? Am I the only one who feels like that?

Comment: If you're actually being bullied, that's what flags are for. However, something tells me you are interpreting someone trying to legitimately help you as bullying. They aren't trolling you, they are trying to get you to think.

Comment: Nah,  it wasn't me,  it was someone else.

Comment: There are no flags for comments,  it'd be good idea to have'em. Most of those reputation lords know that no one can damage their comments.  Also giving reasons for downvoting answers shall be made mandatory.

Comment: What are you talking about? There is most certainly flags for comments.

Comment: I never seen any.

Comment: @Deep You click the flag icon to flag comments.

Comment: And how do I "click"  (rather "tap")  flag if I don't see it?  Are you sure it is there in phone version too?

Comment: @Deep In phone app, first you tap on the comment and then the flag icon will appear

Comment: Nah I'm using browser version.

Comment: It works the same way, tap on the comment text and the flag will appear

Comment: Doesn't works...

Answer (score 9):

Telling someone what the correct terminology for what they're asking about isn't trolling or bullying.  It's being helpful.  Knowing the correct terminology will allow them to more effectively search for information on that topic, and referencing that terminology in the post allows others searching for that term to find that post (if it ends up with a good answer).

Someone being new isn't a reason to refuse to help them understand the proper terms for the concepts they're asking a question about.

Comment: But I wasn't interpreting Bullying,  that poor guy was actually being bullied

Comment: @Deep The only bullying I ever saw when looking through your questions was you personally attacking and insulting people.  You're claiming others are bullying while describing entirely helpful and appropriate behavior, and demonstrating no instances of bullying at all from anyone other than yourself.

Comment: Well well,  "We don't always have access to whole picture "

Comment: Also,   i was  "attacking"  (in your words,  I still think I wasn't)  because I was kinda acting Robinhood.

Comment: @Deep Going around insulting people and attacking them for being helpful isn't appropriate, nor is that in any way analogous to Robin Hood.

Comment: Just if they were being helpful...

Comment: @Deep It's in no way acceptable behavior even if they *weren't* being helpful, not that anyone but you was acting unhelpfully in any example I could find, and you've provided no examples.

Comment: I told you don't know the full story... neither I am going to tell you, why shall I? I just posted one thought from which we all were supposed to do self-assesement.  Whether to take lessons from that or to win arguments by giving political answers is individual choice.  Also,  can you give one example where I bullied any one?  Don't try to attack me otherwise.

Comment: @Deep There are *no* circumstances under which the behavior I've seen of you is acceptable.  No *possible* circumstances would merit what I say you saying in comments.  As you have only ever described others being helpful, that's all I can describe how to respond to. If you can provide examples of others acting inappropriately, we could certainly tell you what *appropriate* responses you have to such behavior.  If you refuse to describe the situations, then all anyone can tell you is what you've already been told, that it's *desirable* behavior.

Comment: @Deep You posted a (now deleted by a moderator) comment in which you swore at people and called them stupid, just because they disagreed with you over the quality of your post.

Comment: Moderator may have deleted inappropriate words,  i do have right to ask what was scope of improvement,  I won't provide with you any further updates on this because I think instead of wasting time on such reputation lords,  I'd rather positively use this time.  Your tries of representing your side were appreciable.  Let us leave rest on fortune of SE.

Comment: @Deep The moderator deleted the whole comment, because all the comment was was you personally insulting people.  It's not *just* the words that you used, but the fact that the whole purpose of the comment was just to insult people, which isn't acceptable even if you aren't using expletives, so it's not like they can just be edited out.

Comment: Nah,  It wasn't the case.

Comment: @Deep Yes, it was.  The comment was once there, no it's not, so it was deleted, not edited.  Also having read it several times I can say that all it was doing was insulting people; there was nothing else it was doing.

Comment: I continue to disagree.

Comment: @Deep Despite providing no evidence at all to support your position, you're merely stating that you're right while not only not providing any basis for that, but actively refusing to do so, meaning your statement holds literally zero weight.

Comment: Did I ask you to weigh em?

Comment: @Deep Yes, you did, by posting a discussion here.  If you have no interest in discussing the topic then you shouldn't have posted a discussion on the topic.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments.